# Azure media encoded and encrypted media player for all platforms

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, jwplayer, azure-media-services

I want to secure my video files using Azure Media services. No one should share and download that media. and should be support all mobile browser, Mac , windows.
I have done that using following steps. I am stuck at some steps, please help me out.
1) Encode my media assets
2) play them using jwplayer(which can be use to play only encoded media in premium version, enterprise version also not support on mobile devices)
I want to use encode and encryption with my media files. so is there any other way where I can encode encrypt and player to play them in all browsers and mobile devices browsers.

Thanks,
Sandeep Modi

Comment: Do you have any media encoded yet?

Answer (score 2):

Check out our new Azure Media Player 
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/15/announcing-azure-media-player/

Mingfei Yan also has a lot of blog posts on our Azure site and on her personal blog that cover the Encryption scenarios. 
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/author/yanmf/

I recommend that you look at enabling simple AES128 clear key encryption first, and then move to PlayReady DRM later if that is required.  PlayReady DRM requires a lot more work to set up and also requires some specialized players on iOS and Android.   If you are not streaming Studio content (in-window movies), then you should be fine with just AES 128 clear key encryption.